# Chess.com rating vs FIDE rating

Tags: rating, online-chess, fide

I've been playing on chess.com standard time (not blitz) for a while with a rating of around 1670, but my FIDE rating is still around 1600, still growing. Is there an actual conversion available for these ratings?

Answer (score 4):

I play blitz there every day for many hours. My rating periodically oscillates between 1850 and 2050, which is a span of 200 points. This has little to do with my varying strength because it depends mostly on which opponents I happen to run into. This phenomenon puts a certain constraint on your idea of a conversion table.

I added two more comments to this answer. See below.

Comment: I think that the very concept of rating as objectively measuring playing strength is flawed. Suppose you had two independent accounts at chess.com and played randomly from one or the other. I suspect that these two ratings would be different all the time oscillating in some span of 200 or 100 points. Then would you ask about a conversion table between two chess.com accounts?

Comment: In 2014, two years ago, my chess.com rating was 1600-1700, now it is 1850-2050, but my FIDE rating hasn't changed much because I play very few games over the board. This is another constraint on the notion of a conversion between an online blitz rating and the FIDE rating.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but I believe the general consensus on this question on chess.com's forums is that your actual ELO/FIDE rating should be lower than your chess.com rating after you get a decent amount of games on both.

I'm not really sure how much lower it should be though. Perhaps the forums on Chess.com hold the answer.